# Wanting a div to align to the right of the screen. Float: right is not working

Tags: html, css

On the bottom, in between the buttons, I have been trying to put the div with the class title on the right side of the screen. I have tried for two days now, looking on many forms, most say float: right, or text-align: right , but that isn't working for some reason. Does anyone know anything that can help???

```css
button {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}

.btn {      
    position: relative; 
    padding: 1.4rem 4.2rem;
    padding-right: 3.1rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: var(--inv);
    letter-spacing: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);  
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.btn:before, .btn:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    transition: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: var(--def);
    transition-delay: .5s;
}

.btn:hover:before {
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn:hover:after {
    background: var(--inv);
    transition-delay: .35s;
}

/* From Top */

.from-top:before, 
.from-top:after {
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.from-top:before {
    bottom: 0;  
    border: 1px solid var(--inv);
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.from-top:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.from-top:hover:before,
.from-top:hover:after {
    height: 100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    --def: #5F4E39;     
    --inv: #9F917E;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-25deg, #7a6954 0%, #5F4E39 100%);
}

html {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}


div {margin-bottom: 3rem;}
div:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}

.title {
    color: #2b2319;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif ;
    text-align: right;
}

.click {
    color: #7a6954;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif ;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="ToneMain.html" class="click">Single-Player</a></button>
    
    <div class="title">T o n e . i o</div> 
    
    <button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="Tone.html" class="click">Multi-Player</a></button>
```

Comment: Aside from the main question issue, in `HTML` you're not allowed to enclose an `a` tag within a `button` or the contrary, you have to choose the best tag for your scenario. In your case, I can see that the anchor tag has an `href` attribute that points to another file, am assuming the `a` tag is to be used here instead of the `button` tag. **PS:** this is not related to your issue of aligning the `div` to the right, that's mainly a semantic mistake.

Comment: There are a couple of things impeding your `float` from working: one is that you have your button positioned using `absolute`, but moreso that the absolute position is combined with `left:0;` in your css. The order of the css matters also (you have button css at the top, even before body) and your `.click` class down the end - all these factors will affect the appearance. Tweak the order and positioning.

Comment: I wanted the button to make the page go to another html file, and I tried many options for a rly long time, and this is what seemed to work. But it only works if you click the text, which is fine temporarily because the text is large, but I am still unsure how to get the button to load the other html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`align-self: flex-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) for the title since body is a flex container. I have also given width `auto` unit instead of `vh` since you wanted it to be aligned to the right of the screen. Otherwise, it stays up to the contained width. You may have to adjust the elements for smaller screens using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width).

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ToneCover</title>
  <style>
    button {
      background: none;
      color: inherit;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      font: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: inherit;
    }
    
    .btn {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1.4rem 4.2rem;
      padding-right: 3.1rem;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      color: var(--inv);
      letter-spacing: 1.1rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .btn:before,
    .btn:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      transition: inherit;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      color: var(--def);
      transition-delay: .5s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover:before {
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover:after {
      background: var(--inv);
      transition-delay: .35s;
    }
    /* From Top */
    
    .from-top:before,
    .from-top:after {
      left: 0;
      height: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .from-top:before {
      bottom: 0;
      border: 1px solid var(--inv);
      border-top: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .from-top:after {
      top: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .from-top:hover:before,
    .from-top:hover:after {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      --def: #5F4E39;
      --inv: #9F917E;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: flex-start;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
      width: auto;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-25deg, #7a6954 0%, #5F4E39 100%);
    }
    
    html {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    }
    
    div {
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    div:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .title {
      color: #2b2319;
      font-size: 120px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
    
    .click {
      color: #7a6954;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="ToneMain.html" class="click">Single-Player</a></button>

  <div class="title">T o n e . i o</div>

  <button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="Tone.html" class="click">Multi-Player</a></button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to move just the title and leave the buttons where they were??? Also, Idk what that line on the right is lmao, is it the background??

Comment: You can try `align-items: flex-start` instead of `align-items: center` on the body. https://nimb.ws/13n5Ld

Comment: The line on the right was because of using viewport units. Changed that to auto.

Comment: Viewport units??? Idk how to get rid of the line ;-; I'm such a noob. I also can't get the body to fit the screen, so that there are no scroll bars ;-;

Comment: I changed background image, to background color, and only stuck to one color, and that fixed the bar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest solution is removing "align-items: center;" in the body class.

Comment: He has already "text-align: right;" in the title class, but the "align-items: center;" in the div class makes the "text-align: right;" from title class not working.

Comment: I removed the align-items: center from the body class, and nothing appears to change

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XOHQEvE It shows me at the left. Or do you want to align it at the right of the window (not right inside the body label)?

Answer (score 1):

remove"align-items: center;" in the body class

Comment: I have done this and it doesn't seem to make any difference, but thx for the response

Answer (score 0):

Putting align-items: flex-start; into body and align-self: flex-end; into title class. Also to fix the bar, I changed backgroung-image to background color and made it a single color. To fix the scrolling issue, I just applied all the body settings to html also.

````
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ToneCover</title>
  <style>
    html {
        height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 5vw;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      }
body {
      --def: #5F4E39;
      --inv: #9F917E;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: flex-start;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 5vw;
      background-color: #5F4E39;
    }
    
    button {
      background: none;
      color: inherit;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      font: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: inherit;
    }
    
    .btn {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1.4rem 4.2rem;
      padding-right: 3.1rem;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      color: var(--inv);
      letter-spacing: 1.1rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
      cursor: pointer;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .btn:before,
    .btn:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      transition: inherit;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      color: var(--def);
      transition-delay: .5s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover:before {
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover:after {
      background: var(--inv);
      transition-delay: .35s;
    }
    /* From Top */
    
    .from-top:before,
    .from-top:after {
      left: 0;
      height: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .from-top:before {
      bottom: 0;
      border: 1px solid var(--inv);
      border-top: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .from-top:after {
      top: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .from-top:hover:before,
    .from-top:hover:after {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    }
    
    div {
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    div:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-size: 120px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
    
    .click {
      color: #7a6954;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="ToneMain.html" class="click">Single-Player</a></button>

  <div class="title">T o n e . i o</div>

  <button type="button" class="btn from-top"><a href="Tone.html" class="click">Multi-Player</a></button>

</body>

</html>```
````